# Tic Tac Toe board layout issue

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to draw a tic tac toe board using VS code under the Jupyter Notebook environment but every time, somehow the vs code doesn't align the pipes properly in the first row. But if I copy and paste the same code directly in Jupyter Notebook, the tic tac toe board appears flawless.

code from VS code (Jupyter Server)

```
from IPython.display import clear_output

def draw_board(board):
    clear_output()
    
    print('    |    |')
    print(' ' + board[7] + '  |  '+board[8]+' | '+board[9])
    print('    |    |')
    print('----|----|---')
    print('    |    |')
    print(' ' + board[4] + '  | '+board[5]+'  | '+board[6])
    print('    |    |')
    print('----|----|---')
    print('    |    |')
    print(' ' + board[1] + '  | '+board[2]+'  | '+board[3])
    print('    |    |')
```

The VS code output:

```
|    |
    |    |  
    |    |
----|----|---
    |    |
    |    |  
    |    |
----|----|---
    |    |
    |    |  
    |    |
```

code from Jupyter Notebook

```
from IPython.display import clear_output

def draw_board(board):
    clear_output()
    
    print('    |    |')
    print(' ' + board[7] + '  |  '+board[8]+' | '+board[9])
    print('    |    |')
    print('----|----|---')
    print('    |    |')
    print(' ' + board[4] + '  | '+board[5]+'  | '+board[6])
    print('    |    |')
    print('----|----|---')
    print('    |    |')
    print(' ' + board[1] + '  | '+board[2]+'  | '+board[3])
    print('    |    |')
```

The Jupyter Notebook output:

```
    |    |
    |    |  
    |    |
----|----|---
    |    |
    |    |  
    |    |
----|----|---
    |    |
    |    |  
    |    |
```

I hope someone is able to pinpoint the error which somehow I am not able to see.